Loss of Logs when using fluentbit storage type as filesystem
I am sending the applications related logs to two different
destinations one is file and other through firehose to opensearch to three different indices based on tags and parsing. Defined with ECS aws service.
My application generates huge amount of logs suppose for every access log It will generate 2779 application logs.
Now we are doing the load Test with the help of Jmeter to generate around 2000 of access logs and sending output to only file thus the total logs I am able to get are around 30k only. Actual logs need to appear are around 5558000.
Below is my configuration
[SERVICE]
    Log_Level debug
    storage.path /tmp/flb-storage
    storage.sync full
    storage.backlog.mem_limit 20M
    Parsers_File /mnt/fluentbit/ecs-parser.conf
[FILTER]
    name multiline
    match *
    multiline.key_content log
    multiline.parser multiline-regex-test
    emitter_mem_buf_limit 400MB
[FILTER]
    Name lua
    Match *
    script /mnt/fluentbit/fbconf/ecs/app/std/logfield.lua
    call fluentbit_fun_log
[FILTER]
    Name parser
    Match *
    Parser access_logs1
    Parser app_logs1
    Key_Name log
    Reserve_Data True
[FILTER]
    Name rewrite_tag
    Match *-firelens*
    Rule $Class ^.*\.accesslog.*$ ${APPNAME}-accesslog-$container_id.log true
    Rule $Class ^(?!\.accesslog$) ${APPNAME}-applog-$container_id.log true
    Rule $log ^[^\"]*$ ${APPNAME}-startup-$container_id.log true
    Emitter_Name re_emitted
[FILTER]
    Name record_modifier
    Match *
    Remove_key  ecs_cluster
    Remove_key  ecs_task_arn
    #Remove_key  ecs_task_definition
    Remove_key  container_name
    #Remove_key  container_id
[OUTPUT]
    Name file
    Match *-firelens*
    Format template
    Template [{time}] {actuallog}
    Path /mnt/fluentbit/fblogs/${APPNAME}
    Mkdir true```

Test Cases :
I have modified storage.backlog.mem_limit with different counts as 50M, 100M, 600M, 700M
although logs are missing even if I try only file output.
When comes to output as opensearch through firehose same count as only to file.
when comes to directly opensearch loss of logs are more compare to above two cases.

Note:
I want to show you some Info of logs in different cases such as :
```[2024/07/02 09:23:20] [ info] [storage] version=1.4.0, type=memory+filesystem, sync=full, checksum=disabled, max_chunks_up=128
    [2024/07/02 09:23:20] [ info] [input:storage_backlog:storage_backlog.3] queue memory limit: 667.6M
    [debug] [output:null:null.2] discarding 22894 bytes

[ info] [input:storage_backlog:storage_backlog.3] queue memory limit: 858.3M
    created flb-storage folder actually


sample logs of a test case.
